# Check if vim is in a comment section

Tags: comments, find

How can I check if the cursor is inside a comment section like this in C:

```c
/*
 * Comment section
 */
```

Or in python:

```python
"""
Doc string
"""
# Comment line
```

My idea for C is, that I just look, what the first characters are but I have no clue how to check, if the cursor is inside a doc string. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Use the generic “get syntax” trick (provided by many plugins, including one of mine, and easy to write yourself):

```
echo synID(line('.'), col('.'), 0)->synIDattr('name') =~# 'Comment' ? 'In comment' : 'Not in comment'
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message: `E15: Invalid expression: >synIDattr('name') =~# 'Comment' ? 'In comment' : 'Not in comment'` Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Ok, I took a look into the help page and changed your command into that: `echo synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 0), 'name')` but this gives me nothing, if I'm inside of a doc string in python. If I'm in a commentary string than it returns `pythonComment` which is fine.

Comment: Oh, the problem was, that the doc-string was empty. Sorry, my fault! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @TornaxO7 I used a more recent method-style syntax; in most cases you can take what’s right of the arrow and make it a function argument (usually the first)